# Proving the convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+z^n}$ for $|z| > 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+z^n}$, $|z|>1$.

There are two facts that my professor uses that I am confused about.

The first is: $|1+z^n| \geq ||z|^n-1|$, I believe this is true for any $|z|$.

The other is: $\frac{1}{|z|^n-1} \leq \frac{2}{|z|^n}$, I believe this is also true for any $|z|$.

Can anyone prove these statements for me?

Comment: in particular, that only holds for $2\leq |z|^n$.

Comment: Now I'm confused--are you asking to prove the two statements, or are you asking to prove convergence?

Comment: @TravisJ The left side and the right side also goes to zero since $|z|^n=|1+\epsilon|^n \to \infty$ for any $\epsilon >0$.

Comment: @travis The term is $|z|^n-1=(1+\epsilon)^n -1 \to \infty$.

Comment: @Dr.MV, yes, my mistake.  But the inequality is still false when $|z|$ is close to $1$.  For example, if $n=10$ and $|z|=1.05$ then LHS is about $1.5901$ and the RHS is about $1.2278$.

Comment: @TravisJ The inequality is not false.  Fix $\epsilon$ first.  Then, you can make $(1+\epsilon)^n$ arbitrarily large by choosing $n$ accordingly.

Comment: @Dr.MV, I have since deleted the comment, but it was for fixed $n$ as $|z|$ is close to $1$.  Close enough to 1 depends on what $n$ is.  I am only looking at the inequality $\frac{1}{|z|^{n}-1}\leq \frac{2}{|z|^{n}}$.

Comment: That inequality holds only when $n>N$, where $N$ is adequately large.

Answer (score 5):

$|1+z^n| \geq |z^n| - 1 = |z|^n - 1$ is true due to the $\triangle$ inequality, and the second one is true if $|z|^n \leq 2|z|^n - 2 \iff 2 \leq |z|^n$, and this is true for some $n \geq N_0$ since $|z|^n \to +\infty$ as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 3):

The first statement is a version of the triangle inequality.

$$\begin{align}
|x|&=|x-y+y|\le|x-y|+|y|\\
&\implies |x|-|y|\le|x-y|.
\end{align}$$

Similarly $|y|-|x|\le|x-y|$. Hence, 
$$||x|-|y||\le|x-y|.$$

The other inequality is equivalent to
$$|z|^n\le 2|z|^n-2$$
or
$$|z|^n\ge 2.$$

Comment: Very useful answer,thank you.