# Prob. 6(d), Chap. 3, in Baby Rudin: Given $z \in \mathbb{C}$, does the series $\sum \frac{1}{1+z^n}$ converge or diverge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence

Here's Prob. 6(d), Chap. 3 in the book *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Walter Rudin, 3rd edition:

> Investigate the behavior (convergence or divergence) of $\sum a_n$ if $$a_n = \frac{1}{1+z^n}$$ for complex values of $z$.

My effort:

If $\left\vert z \right\vert > 1$, then we note that
$$ \left\vert a_n \right\vert = \frac{1}{\left\vert 1 + z^n \right\vert} \leq \frac{1}{\left\vert z \right\vert^n - 1} < \frac{1}{\left\vert z\right\vert^n},$$ 
and the series $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{\left\vert z\right\vert^n} = \frac{1}{1- \frac{1}{\left\vert z\right\vert} } = \frac{ \left\vert z \right\vert }{ \left\vert z \right\vert - 1 } < +\infty,$$
which implies that our series converges if $\left\vert z \right\vert > 1$. Am I right?

If $\vert z \vert < 1$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} \vert z \vert^n = 0$ and so $$\left\vert a_n \right\vert = \frac{1}{\left\vert 1 + z^n \right\vert} \geq \frac{1}{1 + \left\vert z \right\vert^n} \to 1 \  \mbox{ as } \ n \to \infty,$$ so $$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n \neq 0,$$ 
which implies that our series diverges. Am I right?

If $\vert z \vert = 1$, then we note that 
$$\left\vert a_n \right\vert = \frac{\vert z \vert^{-n}}{ \left\vert z^{-n} + 1 \right\vert} = \frac{1}{ \left\vert z^{-n} + 1 \right\vert } \geq \frac{1}{\vert z \vert^{-n} + 1 } = \frac{1}{2},$$
which implies that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n \neq 0,$$ showing that our series diverges. Am I right?

Comment: Your last inequality in your effort is clearly false...

Comment: @DonAntonio which one? Do you mean the following? $$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n \neq 0.$$

Comment: The last inequality in the your first line of equations is wrong. You can get $\frac{1}{|z|^n-1}\le\frac2{|z^n|}$ if $n$ is large enough.

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud *After* ...you wrote "effort". Lutz already made this clear.

Comment: Linked duplicate https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1257017/proving-the-convergence-of-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac11zn-for-z only deals with $|z|>1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Case I: $|z|>1$

Clearly, $|z^n+1|>|z|^n-1\ge\frac{1}{2}|z|^n$, whenever $|z|^n\ge 2$; which eventually happens, say, for $n\ge n_0(z)$, and hence
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{|1+z^n|}=\sum_{n=1}^{n_0(z)}\frac{1}{|1+z^n|}+
\sum_{n>n_0(z)}\frac{1}{|1+z^n|}\le \sum_{n=1}^{n_0(z)}\frac{1}{|1+z^n|}+ \sum_{n>n_0(z)}\frac{2}{|z|^n}<\infty.
$$

Case II: $|z|<1$

Clearly $\frac{1}{1+z^n}\to 1\ne 0$. Hence divergence.

Case II: $|z|=1$

Clearly $\frac{1}{1+z^n}\not\to 0$. Hence divergence.

Comment: I've edited your answer. Do you agree with my edit?

Comment: It fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

An idea: suppose $\;|z|>1\;$ , then apply the limit comparison test:

$$\frac{\left|\frac1{1+z^n}\right|}{\left|\frac1{z^n}\right|}=\frac{|z|^n}{|z^n+1|}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}1\implies\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{1+z^n} \;\;\text{converges as}\;\;\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{z^n}\;\;\text{does}$$

Can you see how to use *exactly the same as above* to get divergence if $\;|z|\le1\;$ ?