# Does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+z^n}$ ($z$ is a complex number) converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, complex-numbers

I am trying to investigate the behaviour of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+z^n}$ where $z$ is a complex number. [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1257017/proving-the-convergence-of-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac11zn-for-z?noredirect=1&lq=1) discussed how to prove it converges when $|z|>1$. But I am interested in a general discussion of its convergence.

My attempt is to use the ratio test:

> The series $\sum a_n$ converges if $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sup \lvert \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \rvert < 1$; diverges if $\lvert \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \rvert \ge 1$ for all $n \ge n_0$, where $n_0$ is some fixed integer.

The challenge is to find a way to discuss the value of $\lvert \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \rvert$ in a concise way. I tried to define $z = a+bi$ and use the binomial theorem to investigate the relation between $z_{n+1}$ and $z_n$. However, the argument easily becomes very complicated. I am wondering if there is a better approach to this problem.

Comment: There is a complete discussion here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2071459/prob-6d-chap-3-in-baby-rudin-given-z-in-mathbbc-does-the-series-s?noredirect=1&lq=1. Mysteriously marked as a duplicate of the $|z|>1$ case.